# Spawn multiple classes and retrieve them

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm wondering if there is a "standard" way to spawn multiple instances of a class dynamically and retrieve them?

The below code spawns 10 bikes, with random prices and colours, I'm wondering how I would call them back? I played around with appending to a list but the returned items are strings.

```
bikes = []

class Bike:

    style = ""
    price = 0
    colour = ""

    def __init__(self, style, price, colour):
        self.style = style
        self.price = price
        self.colour = colour
        self.description = "a {0} {2} worth £{1}".format(self.colour, self.price, self.style)

    def print_details(self):
        print("description: {0}".format(self.description))

for b in range(10):
    price = random.choice(random_prices)
    colour = random.choice(random_colours)
    bike = "bike" + str(b)
    bike = Bike('bike', price, colour)
    bikes.append(bike)

for i in bikes: 
    print_details(i)


Traceback (most recent call last):
print("description: {0}".format(self.description))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'description'
```

Comment: What's the point of `bike = "bike" + str(b)`? It gets *immediately* replaced. Where is your attempt to add the instances to a list, which is exactly what you *should* be doing?

Comment: You can create them using a list comprehension and iterate over that list lis so: `bikes = [Bike('bike', random.choice(random_prices), random.choice(random_colours)) for _ in xrange(10)]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe i was unable to post a screenshot of the code, but i got `str object has no attribute` from the traceback. `bike = "bike" + str (b)` was merely my attempt to rectify the error. The code has been updated to include the class, and my attempt to append the items to a list

Comment: Why do you think we'd want a screenshot? Post the code **as text**. Give a [mcve], and review your indentation.

Comment: I didnt mean screenshot, my bad. Im posting from the stack exchange app, indentations a pain, corrected as best as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you create a class (or any kind of data) it would need to be referenced somewhere. If it isn't, you can consider it lost.

If you need to create a collection of classes, then a collection is probably a good way to store them:

```
bikes = []
for b in range(10):
    price = random.choice(random_prices)
    colour = random.choice(random_colours)
    bike = "bike" + str(b)
    bike = Bike('bike', price, colour) 
    bikes.append(bike)
```

---

Based on your updated question, I believe the issue is in how you're calling `print_details`. Because it's a class member, it should be called like this:

```
for i in bikes: 
    i.print_details()
```

Comment: Code has been updated, this was my original appoach but i was unable to call them back from the list functional. They would come back as strings

Comment: @JONAS402 Updated.

Comment: Item is still a string, i get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'print_details'`